# Is it possible to run next PS3 case from previous case?

Tags: bash, scripts

Let's say I have script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Select option: '
options=("Option one" "Option two")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
    "Option one")
    # few lines of code
    if [ "check that code did everything it was supposed to do" ]
        then
        echo "Completed"
        else
        echo "Something went wrong"
    fi
    ;;

    "Option two")
    # more code
    ;;
    esac
done
```

Now is it possible to change line `echo "Something went wrong"` to command that instantly runs `Option two` without showing PS3 menu again?

Comment: I think this question would be better suited on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I urge anyone thinking of voting to close this question as off-topic to read [Are bash/shell scripting questions on topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "fall-through", and in bash's `case` statements, fall-through is done using `;&` instead of `;;`. However, you can't conditionally fall-through (that is, you can't insert a `;&` in the middle of an `if` block). I suggest that you fall-through always, and `continue` if the code executed successfully:

```
case $opt in
"Option one")
# few lines of code
if [ "check that code did everything it was supposed to do" ]
then
    echo "Completed"
    continue
else
    echo "Something went wrong"
fi
;&

"Option two")
# more code
;;
esac
```